# XamlCompiler error WMC1006: Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'XXX.YYY.ZZZ'

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

We are trying to build Windows8/Xaml application and have problem with reference to one library. Here are more details around our issue:

I have a solution of structure:

1) Project Win8

2) Integration library

3) Web.Models library (this is portable library shared with Web MVC project hosting web.api)

Library 2) uses classes from 3)

Library 1) uses library 2)

so, there is no direct dependency between 1) and 3)

Unfortunately when I try to build my solution then I get error:

C:\Projects\PathToMyWorkspace\ProjectWin8.csproj : 
XamlCompiler error WMC1006: Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'Web.Models.dll'

Did anyone encounter simmilar problem ?

Comment: yes I am facing a similar problem but with System.Web.dll file. Did you manage to find a solution to this?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

We've seen a similar issue. Adding (3) as a (direct) dependency to (1) fixed it in our case. I will admit it feels a bit hackish, though.